# Generating byte of string in with specific size

Tags: c#, hex, byte

I have this code which generate 80 bytes of word 'Administrator' to bellow output.

```
 szOperatorName = BitConverter.ToString(data, 45, data.Length - 45); //szOperatorName is set to 'Administrator'
byte[] OperatorName = new byte[80];

Array.Copy(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(szOperatorName), OperatorName, System.Math.Min(80,szOperatorName.Length));
```

**OUTPUT**

*41 64 6D 69 6E 69 73 74 72 61 74 6F 72 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00*

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

*41 00 64 00 6d **00** 69 **00** 6e **00** 69 00 73 00 74 00 72 00 61 00 74 00 6f 00 72 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00*

I have highlighted some of main deference between two, any help on getting expected result will be much appreciated

Comment: `wordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Administrator")... Array.Copy(wordBytes, newArr, wordBytes.Length)`??

Comment: @T.S. OperatorName is my new variable here which hold generated bytes, what you mean by ??

Comment: check again. ?? - does it help

Comment: It almost looks like your expected output based on Unicode encoding and you use ASCII.

Comment: that didn't work

Comment: it didn't work because your `Data` is not "Administrator". I posted answer I tested in fiddle. "Administrator" bytes are `65
0
100
0
109
0
105
0
110
0
105
0
115
0.....`

Comment: Unicode will add that 00 between each two character ?

Comment: Yes. Because unicode is 2 bytes per character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get expected output use Unicode encoding to get bytes

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(szOperatorName)
```

Test

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Administrator");
foreach (var b in bytes)
    Console.WriteLine(b);

. . . .
Array.Copy(bytes, newArr, bytes.Length);
```

your current output is based on ASCII encoding (obviously)

Comment: You are amazing, do you know that?

Comment: @Pwan This is what she said yesterday :-)